# Firebase Auth doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, safari, firebase-authentication

I have Firebase auth implemented in my web app as suggested in the tutorial:

```
function initApp() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                console.log("no user signed in");
            }
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    initApp();
};
```

This works perfectly in Chrome. The user auth state persists across multiple web pages. I can login on one page and the user profile is still available on the next page.

However this does not work in Safari, the user firebase user object just disappears. I have tried various workarounds by storing the user object in cookies or local storage after logging in but none of them work. How can I make this work on Safari (and other browsers) as well as it does on Chrome?

Comment: By any chance, are you testing this in Safari incognito? If so, note the `localStorage` size is `0` in Safari incognito.

Comment: unfortunately its not private mode

Comment: The auth state is stored in localStorage. If you are not using Safari incognito, can you explain what is causing localStorage to clear? On page load, Firebase Auth checks that the user is still valid before triggering the onAuthStateChanged listener. If the user is disabled or deleted, it would be cleared from storage. If that is not the case, something else is clearing your localStorage.

Comment: Would be useful to set up a demo page to show the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When I was loading the site from finder local storage didn't save the auth state (I don't know why) but when I uploaded the site and accessed it from its URL then everything worked as expected.